Sci-fi novel where a person gains an IQ boost from a drug or treatment
I read a sci-fi novel in the late 80's, I think, with a plot similar to "Flowers for Algernon", but the protagonist was a bank teller (???) who struggled with his work because he was not particularly intelligent. The plot mentions a society where status and jobs are based on how well you perform in tests. The protagonist did not do well in the tests, but then either steals some sort of treatment or something happens to him which greatly boosts his intelligence. He then resits all the exams and blitzes them, eventually challenging a great scientist for the top test scores.
That's all I remember.

In roughly which year did you read this and when do you think it might've been published?

In the late 80's I think, so published before 1990 is my guess - but from tech in novel published after 1960 or so.

Did the plot feature a major antagonist or any danger/action?

No....don't think so. Issue was if the effect was permanent, and if he got noticed for suddenly doing a whole lot better in the tests, by the authoritarian regime. The memory I have is that the whole IQ boost process was illegal/experimental.

Its not IQ 83 by Arthur Herzog

Is this One Against Time (1970) by Astron del Martia...?
As stated in the blurb on the back of the book, the protagonist, Harold Newman, is a bank clerk whose mind is activated by a warp in time, giving him a 'super brain' with the power of twenty computers.

Harold Newman was a loser.
He was a plodding bank clerk whose past was weary and whose future was dull.
Until the moment when his mind was activated by a warp in time and he became a super brain—a brilliant freak gifted with the power of twenty computers.
Suddenly Harold's future wasn't dull anymore.
It was deadly.
His very existence was a threat to the continuance of life on Earth. He knew too much. The World President issued an implacable order through the spiraling levels of space and time:
Search the past! Find the super brain and kill him. But do it now!

In the book, it's noted that he'd previously taken and retaken a 'grouping test,' as a result of which he was classified as Group Five, placing him in the upper forty percent of the population.

Five years after his classification he'd exercised his right to take a final grouping test. Then his last hopes had been dispelled. He'd come out from the test-no worse but certainly no better. The tests were seldom wrong. Time and time again he had been classified as Group Five. He knew then it would be his classification for life.
[...]
His category, Grade Five, had put him among the upper forty percent.

After gaining his super brain, he takes the test again and finds it childishly easy. He then takes more difficult tests until he's ultimately reclassified as Group Twelve. He passed the Group Twelve test in under ten minutes, whereas it took another character named Professor Ryder an hour to do the same.

A broad-shouldered, black-bearded man who stood behind the Administrator pressed forward. His grey eyes scrutinised Newman calculatingly. "Are you the man who tested to Group Twelve in a day?"
[...]
"I'm a Group Twelve myself. At the end of an hour I'd only dealt with three quarters of the Group Twelve problems. I barely scraped through. From what I'm told, you answered all the problems correctly in just under ten minutes. That leaves me only two conclusions. Either you've found out how to beat the group tests; or else you're a bigger brain than I am."

The novel is available to borrow from the Internet Archive.

I think that's it. I will borrow it and get back to you after reading a few pages.
